# How to add custom webform email handler if submission is sticky/flagged

Tags: 8, webforms

I use the bulk operation "Star/Flag selected submission" within webform views to process webform submissions which works nice.

I would like to be able to send an email to the author if a submission of a webform belonging to one of his nodes has been changed to sticky (flag). Is there a way to do this?

I saw that I need to add a custom handler but it is not clear to me with what content.

[image]

Comment: Looking at the source code of EmailWebformHandler.php, I think the best way is to create a new handler, extend the EmailWebformHandler class, and override the buildConfigurationForm and postSave methods. 

That looks like it ought to work.